# Calculating value between squares of two integers

Tags: python

Create a function that takes in a positive number and return 2 integers such that the number is between the squares of the 2 integers. It returns the same integer twice if the number is a square of an integer.

```
def sqApprox(num):
    i = 0
    minsq = 0                        # set lower bound
    maxsq =  0                       # set upper bound
    while i <= num:                  # set 'while' termination condition
        if i * i <= num and i >= minsq:  # complete inequality condition  
            minsq = i

        if i * i > num and i >= maxsq:  # complete inequality condition
            maxsq = i
        i = i + 1                   # update i so that 'while' will terminate
    return (minsq, maxsq)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a homework-completion service.

Comment: please help me tried a lot to get proper output.Not getting..

Comment: I don't think asking homework questions on SO is forbidden, but you should explain in more detail about what's wrong with the code you've provided: for example, give some sample expected input and output and compare with what you actually get.

Comment: "But do my homework anyway" is not going to get people to do your homework for you. Ask a specific question if you have one, but don't just give up and tell us to finish your work for you.

Comment: If i give 2 as num.I am getting correct out put (1,2).If i give 4 as num answer should be (2,2) but i am getting (2,4).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3Thank you for reply. Nothing like that.I am not getting context here.I am new to python.

Comment: How have three people upvoted a homework assignment dump?

Comment: What is the question here?  All I see are directions.  Telling us to do something is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, doing a brute-force search like this is a very inefficient way of approximating square roots. But I guess it's a reasonable exercise if you're just learning how to do loops.

The main problem with your code is that you keep looping after you've found the solution. You also do some unnecessary tests. Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
def sqrt_approx(num):
    i = 0
    minsq = 0
    maxsq = 0
    while i <= num:
        if i * i <= num:
            minsq = i
        if i * i >= num:
            maxsq = i
            break
        i = i + 1
    return minsq, maxsq

#Test it
for i in range(0, 26):
    print(i, sqrt_approx(i))
```

**output**

```
0 (0, 0)
1 (1, 1)
2 (1, 2)
3 (1, 2)
4 (2, 2)
5 (2, 3)
6 (2, 3)
7 (2, 3)
8 (2, 3)
9 (3, 3)
10 (3, 4)
11 (3, 4)
12 (3, 4)
13 (3, 4)
14 (3, 4)
15 (3, 4)
16 (4, 4)
17 (4, 5)
18 (4, 5)
19 (4, 5)
20 (4, 5)
21 (4, 5)
22 (4, 5)
23 (4, 5)
24 (4, 5)
25 (5, 5)
```

Here's a slightly more efficient version.

```
def sqrt_approx(num):
    for i in range(num+1):
        sq = i * i
        if sq == num:
            return i, i
        elif sq > num:
            return i-1, i
```

In Python 2 it would be more efficient to use `xrange()` rather than `range()`, especially if you call this function with large numbers. But as I mentioned above, there are *much* better ways to approximate integer square roots.

---

Here's a new version that handles (non-negative) floating-point numbers correctly.

```
from math import floor

def sqrt_approx(num):
    fnum = int(floor(num))
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i * i <= fnum:
            minsq = i
        if i * i >= num:
            maxsq = i
            break
        i = i + 1
    assert minsq**2 <= num <= maxsq**2
    return minsq, maxsq

for i in range(17):
    j = i 
    print j, sqrt_approx(j)
    j = i + 0.2
    print j, sqrt_approx(j)
```

**output**

```
0 (0, 0)
0.2 (0, 1)
1 (1, 1)
1.2 (1, 2)
2 (1, 2)
2.2 (1, 2)
3 (1, 2)
3.2 (1, 2)
4 (2, 2)
4.2 (2, 3)
5 (2, 3)
5.2 (2, 3)
6 (2, 3)
6.2 (2, 3)
7 (2, 3)
7.2 (2, 3)
8 (2, 3)
8.2 (2, 3)
9 (3, 3)
9.2 (3, 4)
10 (3, 4)
10.2 (3, 4)
11 (3, 4)
11.2 (3, 4)
12 (3, 4)
12.2 (3, 4)
13 (3, 4)
13.2 (3, 4)
14 (3, 4)
14.2 (3, 4)
15 (3, 4)
15.2 (3, 4)
16 (4, 4)
16.2 (4, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.One doubt sir,if I use break satement here,if the condition is true then it will come out of the inner most loop 'if' right?so it will be i + 1. yes added break statement it is working fine,but if i give nums=float number like num=1.2 it should give (1,2) but it is giving (1,0),need to use float?

Comment: @SoorU: Sorry, I didn't realise that you also wanted to handle float arguments. I'll add a new version of your code to my answer.

Comment: thank you very much brother.one doubt it is off topic.I have to practice more.I have to improve my basic knowledge in python.can you please suggest me  book or any other resources to get pythhon basics right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dychotomy to find more quickly the integer square root, because sqrt is a monotonic function:

```
def sqrt_approx(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n,n
    inf =1
    sup = n
    while sup > inf + 1:
        guess = (inf + sup)/2
        g2 = guess * guess
        if g2 == n:
            return guess, guess
        elif g2 < n:
            inf = guess
        else:
            sup = guess
    return inf, sup
```

It only takes O(log2(n)) to find the approximation (you find `sqrt_approx(65535)` in only 16 steps)

Answer (score -1):

```
import math

def func(x):
    return math.floor(math.sqrt(x)), math.ceil(math.sqrt(x))
```